# не срабатывает callback в aiogram 2.x

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

в общем, проблема такая. Написал бота, через какое-то время потребовалось его доработать, плюс появились странные баги - многие функции не срабатывали, хотя должны были. Скачал бота к себе с сервера, не меняя ничего, кроме токена, запускаю и бот тупо игнорит все колбеки. Код, который логически должен работать - не работает. Тогда я написал самого простого бота с инлайн кнопкой, код настолько простой, что там тупо негде ошибаться(хотя я не исключаю ошибку) и все равно колбек не работает. Умоляю, помогите. Версия aiogram==2.25. Сколько раз на stack не писал, ни разу на мой вопрос никто не ответил(

код в скринах:
[image: хендлеры]

[image: запуск бота идет с этого файла]

[image: тут находятся экземпляры классов Bot и Dispatcher]

код не в скринах:
хендлеры:

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup,InlineKeyboardButton


async def start(msg: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton('Start', callback_data='start'))
    await msg.answer(f'Hello, {msg.from_user.first_name}!', reply_markup=markup)


async def some_button_process(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.answer()
    await call.message.edit_text(f'You clicked {call.data}')

def register(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'])
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(some_button_process, text='start')
```

запуск бота:

```
from aiogram import executor
from loguru import logger
from helper import dp
import handler


async def on_startup(_):
    logger.info('Bot started')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler.register(dp)

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=on_startup)
```

код helper.py:

```
from config import TOKEN
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.types import ParseMode

storage=MemoryStorage()

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())
```

Дополнение 1:

Кто-то очень добрый и умный посоветовал мне посмотреть список апдейтов(ну или понятия не имею, что именно)

добавилось в on_startup(_):

```
info = await bot.get_webhook_info()
logger.info(info)
```

вывод в логи:

```
{"url": "", "has_custom_certificate": false, "pending_update_count": 0, "allowed_updates": ["message", "chat_join_request"]}
```

если я все верно понял, разрешены только апдейты в виде новых сообщений и заявок на вступление в чат, а все остальные - игнорируются. Если я угадал, то как это можно исправить?

Comment: А в консоль что выводится?

Comment: пусто, ставил логи, но в функция на колбек вообще не срабатывает. Возможно проблема в том, что версия aiogram 2.x, не знаю, но буквально магия на глазах творится

Comment: @CausonQ я дополнил вопрос, в консоли ничего не выводится(из ошибок), ставил логи внутри обработчика колбека, но они не отобразились в консоли

Comment: Попробуйте явно передать, хотя у вас в коде не обозначено какие именно апдейты вы хотите принимать: allowed_updates=["message", "inline_query", "callback_query"]

Comment: И дополните вопрос кодом из helper, а не скрином

Comment: @CausonQ, а есть вариант прописать прием сразу всех апдейтов? ну как например в регистраторах писать не content_type=[types.ContentType.TEXT, и тд], а прописать content_type=types.ContentType.ANY?

Comment: @CausonQ Вы мой спаситель! прописать явно действительно помогло. Не могли бы вы дать ответ на мой вопрос, чтобы я отметил его, как правильный ответ? желательно с дополнением о том, можно ли передать такой параметр, при котором можно принимать сразу все виды апдейтов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно прописать те апдейты, которые вы хотите получать:
например:

```
allowed_updates=["message", "inline_query", "callback_query"]
```

Полный список апдейтов есть в документации к [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#update), можно перечислить все. Единого какого-то значения, что принимать все апдейты, в aiogram, насколько я знаю, нет. В aiogram 3, если не прописываешь, то, по умолчанию принимается все.

Какие апдейты принимает бот, можно проверить, используя ссылку:
https://api.telegram.org/bot123456:abcd/getWebhookInfo, где 123456:abcd - это токен бота.

Вообще, странно, что у вас бот начал принимать ограниченное количество апдейтов, ип ри это в коде это не прописано

Comment: нашел информацию, в aiogram уже заранее прописаны константы апдейтов, доступны в aiogram.types.AllowedUpdates. Там же можно выбрать all, чтобы принимать все апдейты

Comment: так же хочу добавить, что в aiogram версии 2.9 в start_poling такого параметра, как allowed_upates - нет, но точно есть на версии 2.25

Comment: @Xakum вот только в документации про all нет ни слова

Comment: тем не менее можно добавить такой параметр, есть и он возвращает список всех полей класса AllowedUpdates(то бишь список всех апдейтов, записанных в этот класс)